# Get one's hands on Scabbers

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

> Are you trying to say you broke out of Azkaban just to get your hands on *Scabbers*?

My question pertains to the use of the idiom "get one's hands on". It means to get or **find** something.

Suppose I found the location of someone who is in another city, so technically I cannot touch them with hands, would it be appropriate to use this idiom in that case?

Answer (score 1):

*Get one's hands on* has implications of being able to use or control the thing one has acquired. It usually refers to an object you can literally hold in your hands, though it can be used of getting control of a large sum of money. So, no, it wouldn't be appropriate to use it in the context of locating a person, unless you were a kidnapper!

Comment: The other use of the phrase (get one's hands on someone) is as [a threat of violence](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+my+hands+on+you), but again that requires physical presence.